# JAVA HttpURLConnection I/O Not working

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, inputstream, httpurlconnection

Hello My Respected Seniors **:)**

**My Goal:** Download a URL Resource, given a URL, by using Multi-Threading in Java, i.e. download a single file into multiple pieces (much like how IDM does) & at the end of download, combine all of them to 1 final file.

*Technology Using:* Java, RandomAccessFile, MultiThreading, InputStreams

**Problem:** 
The file is downloaded fine with exact KB size, I've checked many times, but the final file is corrupted. For example, If I download an Image, it will be somewhat blurry, If I download an .exe, it downloads fine but when I run the .exe file, it says "media is damaged, retry download".

This is my **Main code** from which I call to thread class with parameters such as fileName, starting Range and ending Range for a connection as well as a JProgressBar for every thread which will update its own respectively.

```
public void InitiateDownload()
{
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    uc.connect();
    long fileSize = uc.getContentLengthLong();
    System.out.println("File Size = "+ fileSize );
    uc.disconnect();


    chunkSize = (long) Math.ceil(fileSize/6);

    startFrom = 0;
    endRange = (startFrom + chunkSize) - 1;

    Thread t1 = new MyThread(url, fileName, startFrom, endRange, progressBar_1);
    t1.start();
    //-----------------------------------------

    startFrom += chunkSize;
    endRange = endRange + chunkSize;
    System.out.println("Part 2 :: Start = " + startFrom + "\tEnd To = " + endRange );

    Thread t2 = new MyThread(url, fileName, startFrom, endRange, progressBar_2);
    t2.start();
    //-----------------------------------------
    //..
    //..
    //..
    //-----------------------------------------
    startFrom += chunkSize;
    long temp = endRange + chunkSize;
    endRange = temp + (fileSize - temp);    //add any remaining bits, that were rounded off in division

    Thread t6 = new MyThread(url, fileName, startFrom, endRange, progressBar_6);
    t6.start();
    //-----------------------------------------
}
```

Here is **run()** function of **MyThread** class:

```
public void run() {

    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.10.50");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");   

    HttpURLConnection uc = null;
    try  {

        uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        uc.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes="+startFrom+"-"+range);
        uc.connect();
        fileSize = uc.getContentLengthLong();

        inStream = uc.getInputStream();

        int[] buffer = new int[ (int) totalDownloadSize ];

        file.seek(startFrom);   //adjusted start of file
```

***THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE PROBLEM IS***,

run() continued...

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < totalDownloadSize; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = inStream.read();
            file.write(buffer[i]);

            //Updating Progress bars
            totalDownloaded = totalDownloaded + 1;
            int downloaded = (int) (100 * ( totalDownloaded/ (float) totalDownloadSize)) ;
            progressbar.setValue(  downloaded );

        }


        System.err.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + "'s download is Finished!");
        uc.disconnect();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Exception in " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t Exception = " + e );

    }
    finally {
        try {
            file.close();
            if(inStream!=null)
                inStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Now the file is downloaded with complete size, but as I said, a little part of it is corrupt.
**Now,**
If I replace the `for loop` with following `while` loop, the problem is completely solved.

```
int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ (int) totalDownloadSize ];

        file.seek(startFrom);   //adjusted start of file

        while( (bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer) ) != -1 ) {

            file.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        }
```

**BUT I NEED `for` LOOP TO MEASURE HOW MUCH FILE EACH THREAD HAS DOWNLOADED & I WANT TO UPGRADE RESPECTIVE JPROGRESSBARs of THREADS.**

Kindly help me out with the for loop logic.

**OR**

If you can advise on how can I upgrade Jprogressbars within `while` loop. I can't seem to find a way to **quantify** how much file a thread has downloaded...

I've spent alot of hours & I'm extremely tired now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the while loop that works, and then keep track of the total amount of bytes read like this:

```
int totalRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    totalRead += bytesRead;
    file.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    progressBar.setValue((int)(totalRead / (double) totalDownloadSize));
}
```

just remember that `for (a; b; c) { ... }` is equal to `a; while (b) { c; ... }`.